# Opacity in IE + cufon

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, opacity, cufon

I'm trying to add some opacity to a part of a website while using cufon for the fonts. However, it doesn't work. Even worse, opacity doesn't seem to work all around the website, images, divs, text, none of them get opacity.

Using for the cufon:

```
.classname cufon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
}
```

For all the other parts I'm using default opacity as I don't need it to work in IE8 or earlier. However, opacity itself doesn't even work.

```
opacity: 0.3;
```

Anybody has any idea what is causing this? Or any suggestions to solve this?

Demo:
http://web2.expericom.temp.enterexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey now used to `rgba`

```
.classname cufon{
background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

---

more info http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/